# Azure Runbook : What credential to use?

Tags: powershell, azure, credentials, azure-powershell, runbook

I'm trying to create a runbook to restart my web app. I'm new to this so I created a credential in the automation blade but I don't know what is the username/pwd is supposed to be? Is it the same with my azure login account?
Tried that and obviously when I test the runbook this error shows up :

```
Add-AzureAccount : unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
At RestartJob:13 char:13
+ + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzureAccount], 

AadAuthenticationFailedException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.AddAzureAccount
```

Been trying to figure this out on msdn as well.. any help?

Comment: Could you give more information about your script?

Comment: What kind of your account? Microsoft account such as *@hotmail.com @outlook.com?

Comment: Hi, my script is pretty simple
    $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "MyCredential"
    # Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
    Select-AzureSubscription -subscriptionName "XXXXMySubscription"       
    Start-AzureWebsite -Name "hiyuribot1"

At first i thought, yes, it's supposed to be my microsoft account but it seems you supposed to use your AD account? Do I need to make one myself or should I use one that's currently exist? I have one that says : xxxx.onmicrosoftxxxx.xxx (tried that but failed too)

Comment: OK, your account is a Microsoft account? Microsoft account does not support non-interactive login.

Comment: Could you execute your script on your local Windows PowerShell?

Comment: I used the test pane with the webhookdata to test/debug my runbook script

Comment: Yes, I can execute my script on my local windows powershell by typing these cmdlets :
Add-AzureAccount (this will open a dialog to enter my microsoft account)
Azure-RestartWebsite -Name "Mywebsite"

I don't even have to add select subscription command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143073/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-yanuar-tanzil).

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I test in my lab. The fowwling cmdlets work for me.

```
$ConnectionAssetName = "shuitest"

# Get the connection
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionAssetName        

# Authenticate to Azure with certificate
Write-Verbose "Get connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName" -Verbose
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $ConnectionAssetName
if ($Conn -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve connection asset: $ConnectionAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

$CertificateAssetName = $Conn.CertificateAssetName
Write-Verbose "Getting the certificate: $CertificateAssetName" -Verbose
$AzureCert = Get-AutomationCertificate -Name $CertificateAssetName
if ($AzureCert -eq $null)
{
    throw "Could not retrieve certificate asset: $CertificateAssetName. Assure that this asset exists in the Automation account."
}

Write-Verbose "Authenticating to Azure with certificate." -Verbose
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $Conn.SubscriptionName -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID -Certificate $AzureCert 
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId $Conn.SubscriptionID
```

Before you execute the runbook, you should create AssetName and Certificate on Azure Portal.

1.Certificate assets in Azure Automation

Please select `your runbook`-->`ASSETS`--`Certificate`.
[image]

2.Create Connection(AssetName). Please select `your runbook`-->`ASSETS`--`Connections`. According to your scenario, you should select `AzureClassicCertificate`

[image]

Comment: Yes, I just finished testing the Runbook and it seems to work just fine!
Thank you very much, I've been searching for tutorials, etc on MSDN since this morning and you save the day :)

just for information : when I created new automation apparently it comes with the connection and certificates needed for this so I didn't need to create a new one like you suggest and just use the current existed one.

Though I still have a question : when you try to create the certificate, it requires a certificate file to be uploaded. How do I make this?

Comment: Hi, you create a certificate. You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site) to create a certificate. My certificate is created with this link.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Sorry I wasn't marking it as answer before